# Is fate.ffmpeg.org [195.154.232.35] port 22 closed？

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ffmpeg

SZV1000266228:/usr1/wujian/ffmpeg_master # ssh -v -i ffmpeg_sshkey/ffmpegkey fate@fate.ffmpeg.org

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to fate.ffmpeg.org [195.154.232.35] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 195.154.232.35 port 22: Connection timed out

ssh: connect to host fate.ffmpeg.org port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Why are you asking this on SU instead of talking to ffmpeg.org admins?

Comment: How to contact ffmpeg.org admins？

Comment: I mean you already contacted them to get an account on the fate server, didn't you? (Like in the page https://ffmpeg.org/fate.html it says "send the public key to the FATE server administrator who can be contacted at the email address ...") So contact the same people again. It's their private server and they're the ones who know what's up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to contact them.